# Is there a way to set a camera into landscape mode in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

How can you set a camera into landscape mode? Everytime I take a photo, the image gets saved as a portrait image. When the device is in landscape mode the photo looks fine but if I see it in the camera roll it's still portrait mode.
This is my take photo function:

```
// take a photo
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.fullScreenView.hidden = false
    self.recordButton.enabled = false
    self.takephoto.enabled = false
    self.recordButton.hidden = true
    self.takephoto.hidden = true

    session.startRunning()

    // customize the quality level or bitrate of the output photo
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    // add the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to the view and set the view in fullscreen
    fullScreenView.frame = view.bounds
    videoPreviewLayer.frame = fullScreenView.bounds
    fullScreenView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer)

    // add action to fullScreenView
    gestureFullScreenView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.takePhoto(_:)))
    self.fullScreenView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureFullScreenView)

    // add action to myView
    gestureView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.setFrontpage(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureView)

    if (preview == true) {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
            // code for photo capture goes here...

            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                // process the image data (sampleBuffer) here to get an image file we can put in our view

                if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: 1.0)

                    self.fullScreenView.hidden = true
                    self.fullScreenView.gestureRecognizers?.forEach(self.fullScreenView.removeGestureRecognizer)
                    self.session.stopRunning()

                    // save image to the library
                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)

                    self.imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
                    self.imageViewBackground.image = image
                    self.imageViewBackground.tag = self.key

                    self.view.addSubview(self.imageViewBackground)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        preview = true
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

> EDIT

My preview looks like that and that's ok:

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/bildschirmfotom4s7diaehy.png

but in the end it looks like that:

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/bildschirmfoto3c2rlwtevf.png

Answer (score 2):

I use this function, which might be useful to you:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        let orientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

        if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) || UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) {
            if let videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: orientation.rawValue) {
                (captureView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection.videoOrientation = videoOrientation
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is captureView?

Comment: Its a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, it contains the connection

Comment: you can just use `videoConnection.videoOrientation = ...`

Comment: I've edited the post maybe you know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

set videoOrientation for videoConnection object.

E.g.:

videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight

Check device orientation and set videoOrientation to work for both portrait and landscape

Hope this will solve your issue.